# When user press a operator (+,-), He/she do not able to enter another operator until he/she press a digit between a operator

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner in Android studio and I am trying to creat a calculator app. But I facing a problem. I want  this:- When user press a operator (+,-), He/she do not able to enter another operator until he/she press a digit between a operator. Example
I don't want this 1+++ or 1---
I want this 1+1 or 1-1. I can't understand what I will do, please anyone help.

Comment: Your question is so broad and vague it's unanswerable. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, make any attempt to solve your own problem, then post a _specific_ question if and when you get stuck on a step showing what you have done so far.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.